# DatePicker for Foundation 4?

Tags: datepicker, zurb-foundation

Is there a decent date picker (like jQuery UI) that works in Foundation 4? I tried http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example/example.html but that doesn't work. And since Foundation 4 wants to use Zepto.js over jQuery, jQuery UI won't load for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use my port of bootstrap datepicker:
http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/
https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker

We've got full support for foundation 5, (f4 release available), multiple languages available.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Im trying to use this datepicker in Foundation 5 and it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252085/foundation-5-datepicker-failing-or-is-it-me

Comment: @EricB After many days trying to make it work, I have just gave up.
Hopefully there will be a version working in F5.

Answer (score 1):

you can just force foundation 4 to only load jquery by default only by changing:

```
  <script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'javascripts/vendor/zepto' : 'javascripts/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>
```

to

```
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

or your favorite cdn then go crazy with jquery ui, after you include that as well of course.

Comment: this.  you don't HAVE to use zepto.

Comment: Also, zurb has moved away from Zepto in favor of jQuery 2 in foundation 5 so imo it seems worthwhile to just use jquery for f4 projects as well. This also tends to improve compatibility with existing jquery plugins and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I built an interface for Date and Time picking for Foundation.  It's a little fresh, but my company has been using it on a production site and it's holding up.

https://github.com/jockmac22/foundation_calendar_date_time_picker

It supports custom date, time and field value formats so you can have a user friendly display of the date and time, with an ISO standard (or any other format) as the final value stored in the field.

I'll admit that I have no idea how it will work with Zepto, but let me know your thoughts if you decide to try it.